# How to Assign the text for Dynamic loaded Textbox Array in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb6

How to Assign the text for Dynamic loaded Textbox Array in Visual Basic..

> ```
> Dim txtStage1() As TextBox
>
> ReDim Preserve txtStage1(2)
>
> txtStage1(1).Text ="New"
> ```

I am getting error in at `txtStage1(1).Text ="New"` Line..

Can any one help me...

Comment: Is this VB.net or VB6 or VBA?

Comment: From your answer it seems like you are using vb6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer to my question.

Place a `TextBox` on the form and name it `txtarray`. Set the `Index` property of the `TextBox` to `0`.

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
    Dim i As Integer

    txtArray(0).Text = "0"

    For i = 1 To 5
        Load txtArray(i)

        With txtArray(i)
            .Text = i
            .Visible = True
            .Top = txtArray(i - 1).Top + 550
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: That's the correct way, You now have a control array, rather than an array of controls :) While an array of controls can work, you'll need to create each one, and set its container and you can;t easily get events. `Set txtStage1(1) = New TextBox: Set txtStage1(1).Container = Me` With a control array, most of that is done for you and you can receive events.